# How to construct a PFQuery for locations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform

I am constructing a PFQuery to get users within a radius(200 meters), i have set a Location column in Parse custom class in which i store geo locations. I get the users but when i calculate their distances manually through Haversine formula, it turns out to be more than 200 meters. This is my Pfquery:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserLocations"];
[query whereKey:@"Location" nearGeoPoint:geopoint withinKilometers:0.2];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
       compBlock(objects,error);
}];
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How far off are the incorrect results? Can you log `geopoint` and some of the PFGeoPoints being found by the query? It's hard to tell from this code alone, but my first guess would be that the geopoints you're using need to be more precise.

Comment: @KyleParent I am passing this location:
    LOCATION = "<PFGeoPoint: 0x7f974ba37f90, latitude: 33.70110020676594, longitude: 72.96875901077163>";
And getting these locations in response:

LOCATION = "<PFGeoPoint: 0x7f974ba37f90, latitude: 33.701147, longitude: 72.969964>";

LOCATION = "<PFGeoPoint: 0x7f974bd52380, latitude: 33.687297, longitude: 73.031288>"

Comment: @KyleParent first location is fine, but the second one is around 5.98km. You can verify from the following website:
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html